# How to append or prepend on a Scala mutable.Seq

Tags: scala, sequence, scala-collections, mutable

There's something I don't understand about Scala's [`collection.mutable.Seq`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.Seq). It describes the interface for all mutable sequences, yet I don't see methods to append or prepend elements without creating a new sequence. Am I missing something obvious here?

There are `:+` and `+:` for append and prepend, respectively, but they create new collections — in order to be consistent with the behavior of immutable sequences, I assume. This is fine, but why is there no method like `+=` and `+=:`, like `ArrayBuffer` and `ListBuffer` define, for in-place append and prepend? Does it mean that I cannot refer to a mutable seq that's typed as `collection.mutable.Seq` if I want to do in-place append?

Again, I must have missed something obvious, but cannot find what…

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Mutability for sequences *only* guarantees that you'll be able to swap out the items for different ones (via the `update` method), as you can with e.g. primitive arrays.  It does *not* guarantee that you'll be able to make the sequence larger (that's what the [`Growable`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/generic/Growable.html) trait is for) or smaller ([`Shrinkable`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/generic/Shrinkable.html)).

[`Buffer`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/Buffer.html) is the abstract trait that contains `Growable` and `Shrinkable`, not [`Seq`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/Seq.html).

Comment: And it all makes sense now! That was the obvious part I had missed. Thanks!

Comment: Oh. I wonder if this has actually ever been useful to anyone.